# Верно ли утверждение, что абстрактные классы используются для агрегации общих свойств объектов, а интерфейсы для агрегации общих функц. возможностей?

Tags: java

Верно ли утверждение, что абстрактные классы используются для агрегации общих свойств объектов, а интерфейсы для общих функциональных возможностей?

Comment: Помимо общих свойств абстрактные классы таки могут агрегировать общее поведение

Comment: интерфейсы не могут ничего аггрегировать, они не содержат реализацию.

Comment: @tym32167 с 8 java содержат default method и поля

Comment: @Marat охохо, вот это дичь, спасибо, почитаю :)

Comment: @tym32167 а что разве интерфейсы не агрегируют методы без реализации? :)

Comment: [В объектно-ориентированном программировании под агрегированием (или как его еще называют - делегированием) подразумевают методику создания нового класса из уже существующих классов путём их включения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: @tym32167 вы наверное не поняли что в контексте вопроса термин агрегирует имеет другой смысл, т.е. аккумулирует или концентрирует в себе.

Comment: не надо придумывать термины в каких то контекстах, вы потом сами в этом запутаетесь и вас никто не будет понимать. Если вы спрашиваете про агрегирование, которое не отноится к ООП в вопросе о классах и интерфейсах, то это надо явно прописывать в вопросе.